# Disqus popup div vs. Silverlight control Z-Order

Tags: html, css, silverlight, disqus

Playing with Disqus for commenting, but the problem is that we have a Silverlight control for playing video right above the Disqus comments.

Example page: http://play.nimbushd.com/view/lfm7

When an anonymous/not logged in user presses the "Post as..." button to post a comment, the Disqus guest/login div dialog pops up, but is behind the Silverlight control, preventing the user from proceeding any further.

How can I either **fix the z-order**, or **override the Disqus CSS to position the comment popup below the Silverlight control**?

Edit: Screenshot of issue:
[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this Channel 9 post that addressed the issue:

[Overlaying HTML over Silverlight](http://duncanmackenzie.net/Blog/overlaying-html-over-silverlight)

On the `<object>` tag, add `style="z-index: -1;"` and set param `Windowless` to `true` in the Silverlight embed params.

Comment: is it really necessary set the `z-index` css property for the Silverlight object?